# Audio Technica BP4025 for atmos?

Tags: microphone

Has anyone had a chance to try this mic?

How does it compare to a Rode Nt4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one and it's great value-for-money. Robust build, low self-noise, rich sound.

Wrote a lengthy review of it on the blog part of my site, with some sample recordings:

http://www.soundsurvey.org.uk/index.php/survey/blog_comments/1081/

Note re. Rode blimp - the BP4025 does fit into the blimp, but it's not a good idea to walk around for long with the mic mounted inside. The BP4025 has a head-heavy design, and the swaying motion of you walking can make it work its way loose of the suspension.

Comment: fantastic website !!! i love it , especially wildlife section !
i am based in London too and variety of bird songs is fascinating .

Comment: Thanks Rada, glad to hear you got some pleasure from it!

Answer (score 2):

I recently acquired a BP4025 and love it to bits. It's way ahead of the NT4. The BP4025 is rich, sensitive (low noise) with a very pleasing stereo image. I bought it for a field recording trip to Cambodia and it proved to be ideal for the ambient recording I was using it for.

My NT4 sounds brittle and harsh by comparison.

Comment: btw BP4025 fits nicely into a Rycote Baby Ball Gag - a much lighter and more practical solution than a full blimp.

Comment: That's the 21mm model, yes?

Comment: @joe i got the "Rycote 011 002" which is 22mm. Fits snugly in that so I think the 21mm might be a very tight fit.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The specs on Audio-Technica's site say the mic is 21mm in diameter, but I guess I'll try the 22mm model.

Comment: Aha, looks like the 21mm and 22mm models have been replaced by a 21/22mm model. 

Verry interesting.